# Resizing aframe object in the browser

Tags: aframe

I am adding some shapes (circular or rectangular) in a 360 video using A-Frame, I can drag the shape to change its position in the video frame, but I need also to be able to resize this shapes to cover a precise object in the video, let's say I want to cover a painting in a video frame with a rectangle, so I want to be able to resize the shape to cover the painting correctly while I am in the web browser mode. I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65525381/a-frame-super-hands-rotate-grabbed-object) that is asking about rotating the object, and he is saying that he succeeded to do the resize without explaining how exactly he did it. Anyone knows how to do it ?

Comment: how are you dragging them and how do you want to rotate/resize them?

Comment: Here is how the rotation is proposed as an answer in the mentioned post https://glitch.com/edit/#!/foul-pointy-collard?path=index.html%3A1%3A0

Comment: The dragging is done in my app based on this example https://jesstelford.github.io/aframe-click-drag-component/basic/

Comment: If you see the rotation example, you can see a box that you can rotate in the browser what I want to know is if it is possible to resize the box just using mouse in the browser mode... Say like what you do when you resize any shape in any rich text editor like MS Word for example. I hope it is clearer now :)

Comment: Can't make the [drag component](https://github.com/jesstelford/aframe-click-drag-component#browser) work in a fiddle, so I've created an answer on how to rescale objects from scratch. Also check out the [transform controls](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=transf#misc_controls_transform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rescale elements either with the `a-frame` API:

```
element.setAttribute("scale", "1 1 1") // replace 1 1 1 with new values
```

or by accessing the underlying `THREE.js` API:

```
element.object3D.scale.multiplyScalar(scaleFactor);
```

---

You can easily create a component, which would rescale a "selected" element. Run the snipper, press the mouse over an element and use the scrollwheel:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // register component
  AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
    // init callback
    init: function() {
      // react to press / release events to know if the element is selected
      this.el.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
        this.selected = true;
      })
      this.el.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
        this.selected = false;
      })
      // if this is selected, scale up/down when the mouse is scrolled
      this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener("mousewheel", evt => {
        if (!this.selected) return; // ignore when not selected
        const scale_factor = evt.deltaY < 0 ? 1.1 : 0.9 // scale up or down depending on the scroll direction
        this.el.object3D.scale.multiplyScalar(scale_factor);
        evt.preventDefault();
      })
    }
  })

</script>
<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" raycaster="objects: .interactable">
  <a-box class="interactable" position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9" foo></a-box>
  <a-sphere class="interactable" position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E" foo></a-sphere>
  <a-cylinder class="interactable" position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D" foo></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
</a-scene>
```

If you're looking for a ready solution, I'd recommend checking out the [transform controls](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=transf#misc_controls_transform)

---

If you want to resize the plane by moving the vertices to make a custom polygon, You can directly change the planes vertices position:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
    init: function() {
      // grab the threejs mesh
      const mesh = this.el.getObject3D("mesh");
      // grab the vertices array
      // the array is looking like this: x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, ... xn, yn, zn
      const vertices = mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array;
            
      // manipulate the vertices in fixed intervals 
      setInterval(evt => {
        vertices[0] = vertices[0] === -0.5 ? -1 : -0.5; // primitive x1 toggle
        mesh.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true; // toggle update flag
      }, 500);
      setInterval(evt => {
        vertices[1] = vertices[1] === 0.5 ? 1 : 0.5; // primitive y1 toggle
        mesh.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true; // toggle update flag
      }, 250);
    }
  })
</script>
<a-scene>
  <a-plane position="0 1.6 -2" color="green" foo></a-plane>
</a-scene>
```

[Here is an example of moving the vertex around](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/move_vertex.html)

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer, it clarifies how things are executed, but what I want is to be able to do is to use the mouse cursor to scale a rectangle to cover a painting as I said above. I mean to move the corners of the rectangle/polygon like one by one to adjust them into the intended position. The end user will need just to adjust the corners of his rectangle/polygon in order to put them where he wants. The end result will be similar to how the manipulation of the added shapes is done in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yl5Ipe6t4Ew

Comment: ok, so not exactly re-scaling, but more like re-positioning vertices. I have an idea for a plane, I'll add it to the answer

Comment: Yes, you can say vertices repositioning, this will give more flexibility for the user in my case. Thanks for your help, I will be waiting for your idea for a plane :).

Comment: @Hibra I've updated my answer, check out the new snippet (especially the comments) and the linked example

Comment: Thanks alot @Piotr, this is a wonderful job, I think this will solve my problem, I will mark the question as answered, thanks again and again :)